# How can I collect the specific information from multiple similar pages inside a text file?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I collect data from multiple URL similar pages using a loop for every element. (it works)
printing the results. (it works)

Instead of printing, I want to write the results inside one text file. every time the loop collect new page.

```
reference = (
"TY  - THES", 
"AB  - " + abstract1_1, 
"AU  - " + author1_1, 
"DO  - " + uri1_1,
"T1  - " + title1_1, 
"UR  - " + url,
"ER  - ",
"             ")

print(reference)# print works coerctly but I can write inside Refs.txt

myfile = open('Refs.txt', 'w')
myfile.write('\n%s' % i for i in reference)
myfile.close()
```

Comment: write to a file

Comment: the `open` builtin; `f = open("file.txt", "a+") # Create and append` then `f.write("data\n")` amd `f.close()`

Comment: @pVCaecidiosporeadduced thank you, this should be inside the loop?

Comment: yes, then the file creating / closing should be outside the loop

Comment: How to write to a text file the output of for loop, which collects data from multiple URL similar pages.        reference = (
        "TY  - THES", 
        "AB  - " + abstract1_1, 
        "AU  - " + author1_1, 
        "T1  - " + title1_1, 
        "ER  - ",
        "             ")
        print(reference)
        myfile = open('Thesis2_Sort_Refs.txt', 'w')
        myfile.write('\n%s' % i for i in reference)
        myfile.close()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short example,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cmc = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(cmc.content, "html.parser")

with open("soup.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(soup.prettify())
```

When run, a text file will be created called soup.txt. It will contain all of the data you need to web scrape from a website.

Comment: @ Daniel Yoffdan, Thank you, I use a loop for every element to collect the data. So I need only the specific information from multiple URL similar pages to be in the text file.

Comment: Sorry, I did not quite get exactly what you meant. Did you need a clarification on something or were you just telling me that it works?

Comment: How to write to a text file the output of for loop, which collects data from multiple URL similar pages.

Comment: Use mode ```"a"``` which stands for append instead of ```"w"``` when writing to the file. Append adds to the file instead of replacing it. Then in the for loop put the the f.write() command.